# Should you separate Pictures and Video or is it better to have a multimedia section?

Tags: organization

Is there any research or case studies regarding combining pictures and video into one page (multimedia section) is better (or worse) than separating the two into individual sections?

Comment: This is like asking if there's any research on how long a piece of string should be. We need a lot more context here to be of any help.

Comment: I find the website with Galleries and Videos as separate tabs (thus having one for videos and the other for pictures) more user friendly.

Comment: This is something you'll need to test specific to your audience and content. They may be sophisticated users that understand what "multimedia" are, or they may be rubes. Test.

Comment: First of all, thank you for editing my question Erics. Secondly thanks to everyone trying to answer it. We are creating a new white label website that is purchased by publishers and will ultimately serve soccer fans. The end customer varies in all possible demographic aspects so the design should be extremely intuitive. I was trying to streamline the main navigation and give soccer fans (who are very visual) *one* tab where they would find all things visual. It makes sense though that the term multimedia is not clear. Maybe it should be one tab that says "Pictures & Video"?

Answer (score 1):

Have two individual sections. Most of us don't know if a picture is also a type of multimedia.

In fact, don't use such technical words like multi-media, or use it to say 'Pictures, Videos, Other Multimedia'